# Disconnect a peer from PeerJS, on the server side

Tags: peerjs

I have a scenario like this:

1. Peer has to authenticate before it can use the peerjs service.
2. Server waits x amount of time for the peer to send auth.
3. Peer doesn't send auth in x amount of time, so server forcefully disconnects the peer (Must be possible because server restart defaults in clients being disconnected)

Does the peerjs server have a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't via their API.

But, you can with a bit of work! Reading through their source, I was able to create a "mock" of their disconnect. This doesn't provide a reason, however. It still works for my needs!

```
console.log('disconnect peer', id);
this._clients['peerjs'][id].socket.close();
this._ips[this._clients['peerjs'][id].ip]--;
delete this._clients['peerjs'][id];
this.emit('disconnect', id);
```

Comment: What is the `data` variable here? The peer id? Thanks for this code.

Comment: Yep, it appears to the id!